# WebView.setRotation() creates a blank page

Tags: android, webview, rotation

I have `WebView` that is added on top of the running activity. I like this WebView to always show in portrait, so I rotate it if the application is in landscape, but calling `setRotation()` causes the `WebView` to go blank, i.e. setting the rotation to any value that isn't 0 causes the page to show up blank.

I'm not really sure what's happening (I used to think the page just shows up off screen, but it's blank for the smallest of values too), but is there a way to get around this?

Comment: if webview activity is a seperate activity and if you want it to always be in portrait then you can mention in the manifest for the activity its orientation:portrait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My friend found the answer. You have to turn off hardware acceleration.

`webViewInfo.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`

Comment: Helped me. This seems to be a problem on Android 4.2.x (tested on Galaxy Tab 10.1) but didn't affect Android 4.4 (tested on Nexus 5).